# Red Hat 7 GDM + NIS Only Validates First 7 Characters of Password

Tags: rhel, authentication, gdm, bugs

I've come across an interesting issue this morning. We have noticed that GDM on RHEL 7 is allowing us to log-in with only the first 7 characters of password. We can enter anything or nothing from characters 8 onwards and we still get authenticated and logged in. This problem affects all RHEL 7 workstations on the network which use NIS.

I did a quick search around for any potential existing bugs but have not been able to identify anything obvious.

Any suggestions as to if this is a known issue or what may be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known: NIS can use DES (where the short passwords are seen) or other formats which support longer passwords.

Further reading:

- [AJ's Open Source, openSUSE and SUSE Ramblings](http://jaegerandi.blogspot.com/2013/07/nis-and-password-length-fun.html)
- [Migration of NIS yppasswd hashes from crypt to md5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136727/migration-of-nis-yppasswd-hashes-from-crypt-to-md5)
- [Are passwords on modern Unix/Linux systems still limited to 8 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179649/are-passwords-on-modern-unix-linux-systems-still-limited-to-8-characters)

Comment: You should also note that distributing shadow maps with DES passwords via NIS is incredibly insecure.  Its trivial to crack and anyone on the network can grab those maps.

Comment: I think OP understood that.